# Can link in multi level push menu load page AND change panel?

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I plan to work with this menu for a site with a pretty deep hierarchy of products

```
http://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/index2.html
```

Can I code a parent link on any panel to both load a landing page for that parent, as well as set the menu to display the panel that contains that parent's children links?

Top level menu: "colors | sizes | material"

Clicking "colors" loads page about colors offered, and the menu now contains a child panel with "reds | blues | greens"

When I inspect what's going on, the parent click transitions to position of the panel, so I'm assuming that change would need to be maintained when loading the new url.

I'm surprised I could not find anything about this, but maybe I'm just using the wrong search wording.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: why not ask the plugin author ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have already asked the plugin author.  Not heard back.